# My laravel doesn't show image though sybolic link is right

Tags: laravel

I typed `php artisan storage:link` and below is my symbolic link.

```
ls -la public
storage -> /home/arosotomakas/Desktop/recipehouse_laravel/storage/app/public
```

This is a screenshot of my public and storage directory.

[image]

[image]

And Below are codes for the display function.

```html
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'. $recipe->file_path) }}">
<img src="{{ asset('storage/tesuto1.png') }}">
<img src="{{ asset('public/storage/tesuto1.png') }}">
<img src="../../../storage/{{$recipe->file_path}}" alt="recipe image">
```

[image]

This is my console error in developer tool.

[image]

Where is the wrong in my setting?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: perhaps a file permission issue?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. storage and public folder belong to my user.

Comment: Check the browser console, what error are you getting? what happens if you click on each of those links? we need more info

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.
I added my console error.
I didn't know the meaning of the error.

Comment: I now solve the error.
I will add answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to type `./vendor/bin/sail php artisan storage:link.`

I accidentally typed `php artisan storage:link`